# How to change Request before submitting data to a Form?

Tags: request, symfony, json-api

I'm building an API with Symfony 3 following the JSON API specification ([Documentation](http://jsonapi.org/)).

When submitting new data, the request has this format :

```
{
  "type": "entity",
  "id"  : null,
  "attributes" : {
    "name" : "Test name"
  }
}
```

But the problem is the request does not fit the format expected by symfony's Forms because of the extra object `attributes`.

So I want to be able to transform the request before the form submit in order to make the form able to populate the underlying Entity.

I have tried to register an `FormEvents:PRE_SUBMIT` and do the logic in it but it seems I have no access to the Request content.

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $data = $event->getData();

            var_dump($data);
            die();
        });
```

The `$event->getData()` is `null`.

I have also see there is possibility to register `DataTransformer` but it is registered per field, and has no access to the Request too.

I don't want to do it manually in the Controller as this will occur on all my forms (or at least the majority), so I search for a more generic way to transform the request, but at this point I can't figure out how to do this.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `EventListener` does not have access to your `Request`, nor does your `Form` itself.

The best and cleanest way to do this in my opinion would be to define a custom `RequestHandler` for your `Forms`, extending the [`NativeRequestHandler`](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/NativeRequestHandler.php) that parses your `Request` by default.

Then you only need to execute `$builder->setRequestHandler()` to apply this to your Forms.

Comment: It's exactly what I'm looking for. I have read the entire Symfony 2 documentation and CookBook and I can't remember it explains you can do this. Is it a new feature of Symfony 3 or is it just not documented ?

Comment: Not documented apparently, this seems to exist since Symfony 2.3

Comment: The drawback is I will need to duplicate some inner logic (such as `$_FILES` and method validation) as all the methods are `private`. Just a little downside as it's cleaner than all solutions which I thought.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if there is a particular best practice to implement this better than copy-pasting the private methods. I guess at least you will have a good control of how your Request are managed :) Good luck!